# How to configure authentication & Authorization in Mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

I'm developing a website which includes a log-in to customers and sellers ,so the users & sellers can log-in and maintain their profiles. I created the Mvc project by selecting "No authentication".But now i need to add authentication to my project.I followed the database first approach to create the model.So i have the table called "User" to store information about users.Can i do the authentication using that table?(It includes Id,Email,Password,etc).If yes, How do i do that? What are the packages i need to install? what are the modifications i need to do in web.config file?(I saw something related to this in a tutorial)

I also need to restrict various services(pages) to users by using authorizing.For a example if the user is a seller he/she will be able to edit their product details,but not the customers..Please suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: This may help you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with minimal coding using ASP.NET identity which provides the Authentication and Authorization out of the box. Below article by Ben Foster can help you with that.

[Part 1](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1)

[Part 2](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2)